# Permission denied error while installing MATLAB 2017 a on ubuntu16.4

Tags: xubuntu, ubuntu-gnome, ubuntu-mate, linux-headers, user-mode-linux

i tried to install MATLAB 2017a the first i used ./install and got permission denied error the next made super user and that error repeated again.
This is whole of my installation process:

```
reza@reza:~$ cd /home/reza/Desktop/matlab-linux/1

reza@reza:~/Desktop/matlab-linux/1$ ./install
./install: 1: exec: /home/reza/Desktop/matlab-linux/1/bin/glnxa64/install_unix: Permission denied

reza@reza:~/Desktop/matlab-linux/1$ sudo bash
[sudo] password for reza: 

root@reza:~/Desktop/matlab-linux/1# ./install
./install: 1: exec: /home/reza/Desktop/matlab-linux/1/bin/glnxa64/install_unix: Permission denied
```

Pls help?. tanx.
+ permission denied on install file.

Comment: Please run that file like this `sudo  ./install`

Comment: I did . It's not worked@George

Comment: What exactly are the permissions on the file? check with `ls -l /home/reza/Desktop/matlab-linux/1/bin/glnxa64/install_unix`

Comment: retrun this: -rw-r--r-- 1 reza reza 29445 jan 20 2017 /home/reza/....  @steeldriver

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the execute permission bit to allow execution of the file. Try running `chmod +x install` in the terminal before executing the installer.

Comment: I used .that not worked .

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information provided thus far, it appears the permissions on /home/reza/Desktop/matlab-linux/1/bin/glnxa64/install_unix are wrong.  It does not have "execute" permissions.

Try:  chmod +x /home/reza/Desktop/matlab-linux/1/bin/glnxa64/install_unix

But if that file has the wrong permissions, it makes one wonder if other files have the wrong permissions.  Perhaps re-download the installer or try unzipping with a different utility?